# Function should only be called if conditions are true and multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

The problem I have is: in a multi threaded simulation of a print-server, I need to do some thing like:

```
// in client
if (printer.isAvailable() && printer.isFair(this)) // is fair checks if its fair to allow client to print now
    printer.requestToPrint(something)
else
    printer.requestToPrintNext() // something like go into queue
```

The problem is: `requestToPrint` should not be called if either `printer.isAvailable() == false` or `printer.isFair(client) == false` (even within function). How can I ensure this? The simple way might be to wrap everything in `synchronized (printer)`? But that will mean I will just have 1 client trying to print at any one time, `requestToPrintNext` will never be called? How might I solve this problem?

Btw, all these functions are defined in an `Interface` provided thus I think I need to use all of them...

Comment: What is `this` in `printer.isFair(this)` ?

Comment: You have ensured it. Not a real question.

Comment: @Santosh, its a function that checks if its fair to allocate printer to a client. It simply returns a boolean. I think the main problem here is I have a check which is not synchronous then a function call. Which means that >1 thread can have the conditions evaluated to true, try to call the function, which 1 thread will cause the `isAvailable` to evaluate to false. Meaning the other threads call to `requestToPrint` will be invalid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From first glance it appears that your clients have too much of the printer logic in them.  I would think that the client's would have a method more like:

```
public void printMe() {
    printer.print(this);
}
```

And the **printer** would be handling all the available checking and queuing and dispatching:

```
public synchronized boolean print(Client c, Something something) {
    if(isFair(c) && isAvailable()) {
        requestToPrint(something);
    }
    else {
        // queue
        // Not sure what "requestToPrintNext" does, 
        // as it has no argument, like "something"
    }
}
```

A synchronized print method would keep other clients from stepping over each other (the next client would be blocked until the method completes for the current client).  As other posters have mentioned, if the `requestToPrint` method takes a long time you could thread it out (just make sure that it somehow sets isAvailable to false first so the next client will get queued up properly).

The above `print` method assumes that the `requestToPrint` method simply triggers a print job, and **does not** block for the entire printing operation.  An example implementation might be something like:

```
public void requestToPrint(Client c) {

    setAvailable(false);

    Thread job = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            // The actual print work

            setAvailable(true);
        }
    });

    job.start();
}
```

It might be worth noting that this implementation is quite specific to the constraints of this question.  For a more general approach, the single *print queue* (as referenced by other answers) with a single Worker Thread to service that queue would be much cleaner overall.  A very simple skeleton would be:

```
public void print(Client c) {
    synchronized(queue) {
        queue.add(c);
    }
}

public class PrintWorker implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(true) {
            Client c = null;
            synchronized(queue) {
                if(!queue.isEmpty()) {
                    c = queue.remove(0);
                }
            }

            if(c != null) {
                // do print work
            }
            else {
                // maybe add sleep or wait here
                // to keep thread from spinning
                // too fast and burning CPU
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, I guess thats the right way ... I am given the functions as part of an interface (its a sch assignment), thus I think I need to use them, if by "print now" u mean call `requestToPrint`, I think it will cause the same problem since another thread might pass the condition check and try to execute the function too

Comment: @JiewMeng Added `synchronized` to the method to address your concern.  Are you not allowed to *modify* the Interfaces?  Normally adding additional helper methods is not a violation, unless you don't have control over the interface at all.

Comment: I will try that later. But is my understanding wrong: if the method is synchronized, only 1 thread can enter? Meaning there is no queue? Guess my understanding is wrong somewhere? Since isAvailable() is kind of ensured by synchronized, and if there is no one waiting, it will be fair to allocate the printer to the thread?

Comment: @JiewMeng: Yes, with `synchronized`, only one thread can be in the method at a time (with the same printer instance).  I guess the question is: Does `requestToPrint()` actually **do** the printing? Like does it block until the printing is complete?  If so, you probably would want to thread the actual printing work out so that the `print` method would complete so the next client could enter (and get queued).

Answer (score 2):

Usual way to deal with printer is to organize print jobs in a queue, with single interface function, which starts printing immediately if the printer is free, otherwise puts the job in the queue. If the provided interface has such a function, use it. If not, create your own. If printing is synchronous, that is, does not return until all is printed, call it from separate thread.